# New Version of Chrome cannot render dd function in network preview window Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to share live saver with people who debugging with dd() and have to refresh every time because it gets status 200 and stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]If you want to change status to 500 for your ajax requests you just need to update

project/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php
class on line 111 where dump() method exists.
Just add line `http_response_code(500);` at the beginning of function. It works for Laravel 5.6 version.

Answer I found in: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21808

Comment: This is a terrible workaround. You know that what you change in the vendor is not persistant ? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21808#issuecomment-404725116 this one is a much more acceptable answer

Answer (score 0):

See my solution at

https://gist.github.com/fontenele/7625cb71c0a8356213abc727278b48d5

I created a new helper, get the content, replaced div for span because google does not permit `<DIV>` tags in DevTools.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper;

if (!function_exists('_dd')) {
    function _dd(...$args)
    {
        $content = '<span>';
        ob_start();
        foreach ($args as $x) {
            (new Dumper)->dump($x);
        }
        $content .= ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $content.= '</span>';
        $content = str_replace(['<div', '</div>'], ['<span', '</span>'], $content);
        response()->make($content, 500, ['Content-Type' => 'text/html'])->send();
        die(1);
    }
}
```

**Updated**
Lumen:

```
function _dd(...$args)
    {
        $content = '<span>';
        ob_start();
        dump(...$args);
        $content .= ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $content .= '</span>';
        $content = str_replace(['<div', '</div>'], ['<span', '</span>'], $content);
        response()->make($content, 500, ['Content-Type' => 'text/html'])->send();
        die(1);
    }
```